# Join unrelated data in a table

Tags: jquery, excel, excel-2013, vba

Im looking for a solution for automating the creation of a table which repeats our customer names against a pre defined month and result column.

I have tried to loop through vba but the result is slow and unusable. I have also tried using Microsoft query and adding both tables and just not joining the tables. This works until an update is made in the base data, which causes the second table to disappear. I'm looking for a stable solution which will maintain structure.

The resulting table is used to build a concatenate formula which is used to count matching entries in other worksheets.

An example of the data is below;

```
Customer names:
Adam
Anne

Month    Result
Jan      Pass
Jan      Fail
Jan      Exclude
Feb      Pass
Feb      Fail
Feb      Exclude
```

Desired output:

```
Name  Month    Result
Adam  Jan      Pass
Adam  Jan      Fail
Adam  Jan      Exclude
Adam  Feb      Pass
Adam  Feb      Fail
Adam  Feb      Exclude
Anne  Jan      Pass
Anne  Jan      Fail
Anne  Jan      Exclude
Etc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope you can figure out the cell refernces

```
Sub tabulate()
Dim custNames As Range
Dim data As Range

Set custNames = Range("A2:A3")
Set data = Range("A6:B11")

For i = 1 To custNames.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To data.Rows.Count
        Range("E1").Offset((i - 1) * data.Rows.Count + (j - 1), 0) = custNames(i, 1)
        Range("F1").Offset((i - 1) * data.Rows.Count + (j - 1), 0) = data(j, 1)
        Range("G1").Offset((i - 1) * data.Rows.Count + (j - 1), 0) = data(j, 2)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work to add all the different combinations:

```
Sub compare()
    Dim CustNames()
    Dim MonthName, count, row
    ReDim CustNames(1)
    CustNames(0) = Range("A2").Value
    CustNames(1) = Range("A3").Value
    row = 0
    Range("C1").Select
    For j = 1 To 12 Step 1
        count = 0
        For i = 0 To (UBound(CustNames) + 0.5) * 3 Step 3
            Select Case j
                Case 1
                    MonthName = "Jan"
                Case 2
                    MonthName = "Feb"
                Case 3
                    MonthName = "Mar"
                Case 4
                    MonthName = "Apr"
                Case 5
                    MonthName = "May"
                Case 6
                    MonthName = "Jun"
                Case 7
                    MonthName = "Jul"
                Case 8
                    MonthName = "Aug"
                Case 9
                    MonthName = "Sep"
                Case 10
                    MonthName = "Oct"
                Case 11
                    MonthName = "Nov"
                Case 12
                    MonthName = "Dec"
            End Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(row, 0).Range("A1").Value = CustNames(count)
            ActiveCell.Offset(row + 1, 0).Range("A1").Value = CustNames(count)
            ActiveCell.Offset(row + 2, 0).Range("A1").Value = CustNames(count)
            ActiveCell.Offset(row, 1).Range("A1").Value = MonthName
            ActiveCell.Offset(row + 1, 1).Range("A1").Value = MonthName
            ActiveCell.Offset(row + 2, 1).Range("A1").Value = MonthName
            ActiveCell.Offset(row, 2).Range("A1").Value = "Pass"
            ActiveCell.Offset(row + 1, 2).Range("A1").Value = "Fail"
            ActiveCell.Offset(row + 2, 2).Range("A1").Value = "Exclude"
            count = count + 1
            row = row + 3
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```